# Why the cube is transparent on the canvas/panel ui?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to animate the cube over the ui panel.

The Canvas is set to Render Mode : Screen Space - Overlay
The Panel have my own source image
The Camera Clear Flags set to Skbox and Culling Mask to UI only
The Cube layer is set to UI

But the Cube is transparent and I want it to be full like a regular Cube.

[image: Cube is transparent]

Comment: Pretty sure the cube is solid and the landscape image is transparent (and rendering on top of the cube).

Comment: Is the camera on the same side of the cube?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think @Draco18s is right, for you to render UI behind stuff you need to change the Canvas to Camera or World space and then configure Z position in transform of the background (or depth in canvas component) to make it stay behind your cube.

Remember to add a camera to the canvas.